# Entity with nullable ValueObject. How should validate the ValueObject?

Tags: domain-driven-design, entity, value-objects

I'm studying DDD for a while and I still have a lot of doubts when I write code using DDD. I've this scenario:

I've a ValueObject **Email**:

```cs
public class Email : IValueObject {
    private string _email = string.Empty;
    public string Value { get => _email; }

    private Email( string email ) {
        _email = email;
    }

    public static ErrorOr<Email> Create( string email ) {
        var emailValue = new Email( email );

        var errors = Validate( emailValue );

        if ( errors.Any() ) {
            return errors;
        }

        return emailValue;
    }

    public static List<Error> Validate( Email email ) {
        try {
            var emailValidator = new MailAddress( email.Value );
            return new List<Error>();
        }
        catch {
            return new List<Error>() { Common.Errors.Errors.Generic.InvalidEmail };
        }
    }
}
```

An Entity called **Agency**:

```cs
public sealed class Agency : StatefulBaseEntity, IAggregateRoot {
    private string _name;
    private Email _email;
    private Email? _pecEmail;

    public string Name { get => _name; }
    public Email? PecEmail { get => _pecEmail; }
    public Email Email { get => _email; }

    public Agency(
        string name,
        Email? pecEmail,
        Email email,
        Guid id )  {
        _name = name;
        _pecEmail = pecEmail;
        _email = email;
        _id = id;
    }

    public static ErrorOr<Agency> Create(
        string name,
        Email? pecEmail,
        Email email,
        Guid? id = null ) {

        var agency = new Agency(
            name,
            pecEmail,
            email,
            id ?? Guid.NewGuid() );

        var errors = Validate( agency );

        if ( errors.Any() ) {
            return errors;
        }

        return agency;
    }


    private static List<Error> Validate( Agency agency ) {
        var errors = new List<Error>();
        errors.AddRange( Email.Validate( agency.Email ) );
       
        if ( agency.PecEmail is not null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty( agency.PecEmail.Value ) ) {
            errors.AddRange( Email.Validate( agency.PecEmail ) );
        }
        
        return errors;
    }
}
```

And a CommandHandler that create and save the new Agency:

```cs
internal sealed class CreateAgencyCommandHandler
    : IRequestHandler<CreateAgencyCommand, ErrorOr<AgencyResult>> {
    private readonly IAgencyRepository _agencyRepository;

    public CreateAgencyCommandHandler( IAgencyRepository agencyRepository ) {
        _agencyRepository = agencyRepository;
    }

    public async Task<ErrorOr<AgencyResult>> Handle(
        CreateAgencyCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken ) {
    
        var agency = Agency.Create(
            request.Name,
            Email.Create( request.PecEmail ).Value,
            Email.Create( request.Email ).Value );

        if ( customer.IsError is not true ) {
            _agencyRepository.Add( agency.Value );
            return new AgencyResult( agency.Value );
        }

        return await Task.FromResult( agency.Errors );
    }
}
```

In my case, Agency can accept a nullable Email "pecEmail" and a not nullable "Email". **If the "pecEmail" is not null I have to check if is correct**. If not, I should return an error.

My question is: How should check the validation of the Email? The entity or the CommandHandler?

1. In the first case, the Entity should check the validity of the Email if is not null, but the ValueObject exist if only is valid! So, theorically, I can not pass an "invalid" ValueObject/Email.
2. If the CommandHandler should check the validity of the ValueObject/Email, this will force me to do a lot of duplicated code inside my CommandHandlers that need to create a new Agency. For example Create, Update etc etc.

So, what's the best solution? I prefer to delegate the integrity to the Agency Entity, so the Agency Entity know what's is valid for it and I'm not forced to duplice check inside of my CommandHandlers.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Value object validation is meant for data consistency issues, validation to say to the user "ehi you wrote a wrong email address" is a different concern.  Here a link that can help https://verraes.net/2015/02/form-command-model-validation/

Comment: Ok, so, reading the article I've to put the logic inside the CommandHandler. The Agency Entity will accept always valid VO. That's ok for me, but this will force me to write some duplicate code inside the CommandHandlers. Probably I can incapsulate a "ModifierAgencyCommandHandlerRules" that helps me to incapsulate all the rules shared for Agency use cases?

Btw, anothe interesting article is here: https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/nulls-in-value-objects/

Comment: I don't think your issue is related to nulls at all...going back to your question, you posed two option, but option 1 seems to don't have any problem, you will never receive a wrong email address, what's the issue with that option?

Comment: It would be useful to see the `ErrorOr` class. I'm not sure what `Email.Create(...).Value` refers to